# In C : How to detect line ending

Tags: c, matrix, sparse-matrix, space, detect

I'm doing a program to show the nonzero item in n*n matrix

ex. 
first. I will input the row & col

then input the matrix that I want to analysis.

problem is here!

for example , if I want to have a 4*4 matrix

my input type will like:

```
input:    
    0 0 4 0
    0 4 0 5
    1 7 5 8
    1 0 5 4
```

and I want to output "error" when someone input 4*4 like that
(this is 2*12)

```
input:
    1 0 4 2 0 4 1 4
    5 0 1 4 8 0 0 4
```

or that(even not square)

```
input:
   1 2 4 2 5 4 1 7 8 1
   4 5 7 0 0 5


  #include <stdio.h>
  void main(){

  int i;
  int j;
  int row;
  int col;

  printf("Please Enter Row & Column : ");
  scanf("%d%d",&row,&col);

  int a[row][col];

  printf("Please Enter Matrix: \n");
  for (i=0; i<row; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<col;j++){

       scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
       }
  }

  int size =0;
      for (i=0;i<row;i++)
          for (j = 0; j <col; j++)
              if(a[i][j] != 0)
                  size++;

  int b[size][3];


      int k = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
          for (int j = 0; j <col; j++)
              if (a[i][j] != 0)
              {
                  b[k][0] = i;
                  b[k][1] = j;
                  b[k][2] = a[i][j];
                  k++;
              }
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
      {
          for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
              printf("%d ", b[i][j]);

          printf("\n");
      }
      return 0;

  }
```

Comment: Use `fgets`. Then parse the lines.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use `scanf`.

Answer (score 4):

Create a buffer and read the whole line with `fgets`. Then use `strtok` and `strtol` to parse the integers.

`fgets`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets

`strtok`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok

`strtol`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol

And here is a sample code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 65535
#define M_SIZE 4

int main() {
    char buf[MAXLEN];
    int matrix[M_SIZE][M_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < M_SIZE; i++) {
        // read the whole line
        fgets(buf, MAXLEN, stdin);

        char* num_str = strtok(buf, " ");  // get first integer
        for (int j = 0; j < M_SIZE; j++) {
            if (num_str == NULL) {
                printf("less than 4 integers inputted in one line\n");
                return -1;
            }
            matrix[i][j] = strtol(num_str, NULL, 10);
            num_str = strtok(NULL, " ");  // get next integer
        }

        if (num_str != NULL) {  // if the next integer exists
            printf("more than 4 integes inputted in one line");  // this is the error you want
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Another way is to use `sscanf` according to the comment

`sscanf`'s behavior is the same as `scanf` except it takes a string as input. It returns the argument it has parsed. Putting an '%n' in the format string will  put the number of characters read so far in the assigned int, and it wont increase the count returned by the function. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 65535
#define M_SIZE 4

int main() {
    char buf[MAXLEN];
    int matrix[M_SIZE][M_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < M_SIZE; i++) {
        // read the whole line
        fgets(buf, MAXLEN, stdin);

        int parsed_len;
        int ret = sscanf(buf, "%d %d %d %d %n", &matrix[i][0], &matrix[i][1], &matrix[i][2], &matrix[i][3], &parsed_len);  // parse the line
        if (ret < 4) {
            printf("less than 4 integers inputted in one line\n");
            return -1;
        }
        else if (parsed_len == strlen(buf)) {
            printf("more than 4 integes inputted in one line\n");  // the error you want
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's much simpler and easier to use `sscanf` to parse the line -- just be sure to check the return code and use `%n` to see how much of the line each `sscanf` call consumed.

Comment: `strtok` is not necessary.  By passing a value as the second argument to `strtol`, you essentially get the tokenization from `strtol` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
/* Read text data into an array. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct args {
        int rows; /* number of rows in the matrix */
        int cols; /* number of columns in the matrix */
};
void die(const char *fmt, ... )  __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)));
void usage(const char *name);
void parse_args(int argc, char **argv, struct args *A);


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct args A;
        int row=0, col=0; /* indices into the array */

        parse_args(argc, argv, &A);

        int a[A.rows][A.cols];
        char buf[1024];
        char *end;
        while( fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) ) {
                if( row >= A.rows ) {
                        die("Too many lines of input");
                }
                for( end=buf, col=0; col < A.cols && end < buf + sizeof buf; col++ ) {
                        char *s = end;
                        a[row][col] = strtol(end, &end, 10);
                        if(! isspace(*end) || (end == s)) {
                                die("invalid input at line %d, column %ld: '%c'",
                                         row + 1, end - buf + 1, *end);
                        }
                }
                if(col != A.cols) {
                        die("missing inputs in line %d.", row + 1);
                }
                while(isspace(*end)) {
                        end += 1;
                }
                if( *end ) {
                        die("extra data in line %d", row + 1);
                }
                row += 1;
        }
        for( row=0; row < A.rows; row++ ) {
                printf("%d: ", row);
                for(col=0; col < A.cols; col++) {
                        printf("%d  ", a[row][col]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}

void die(const char *fmt, ... )
{
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        fputc('\n', stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void
usage(const char *name)
{
        const char *base = strrchr(name, '/');
        printf("usage: %s rows columns", base ? base + 1 : name);
        puts("\n\nrows and columns must be positive integers");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void
parse_args(int argc, char **argv, struct args *A)
{
        char *end;
        int ch;
        if( argc < 3 ) {
                usage(argv[0]);
        }
        while( (ch = getopt(argc, argv, ":bf:")) != -1 ) {
                switch( ch ) {
                case 'h': usage(argv[0]);
                default: die("Unexpected option: %s (-h for usage)", argv[optind-1]);
                }
        }
        argc -= optind;
        argv += optind;
        A->rows = strtol(argv[0], &end, 10);
        if( A->rows < 0 || *end ) {
                die("invalid parameter: %s (-h for usage)", argv[0]);
        }
        A->cols = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
        if( A->cols < 0 || *end ) {
                die("invalid parameter: %s (-h for usage)", argv[1]);
        }
}
```

but I would argue that you shouldn't.  That input format is really inappropriate.  If you have unstructured data like that, you should insist that the producer use a better format.  If you cannot change the producer, then you should use a different language to modify the data to make it more appropriate.  For example, your C code can simply be:

```
/* Read integer data into an array. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        unsigned rows, cols;

        if( argc != 3 ||
                ( rows = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10)) == 0 ||
                ( cols = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10)) == 0
        ) {
                fputs("invalid parameters\n", stderr);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        int a[rows][cols];

        if(fread(a, sizeof **a, rows* cols, stdin) != rows * cols) {
                fputs("Unexpected EOF\n", stderr);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
}
```

and given a text input file, you can use it with:

```
perl -ane 'print pack("i*", @F)' input | ./a.out ${N?} ${M?}
```

Note that this will now work with an input file in which all of the data is on one row, or if the data is structured incorrectly.  (eg, one row with 5 entries and another row with 3 entries could be read as a 2x4 matrix or a 4x2).  Whether or not this is a problem or a feature is in the eye of the beholder.  If it's a feature, nothing need be done.  If it's a problem, put the error checking in the filter (eg, the `perl`), not in the C code.  If you do want to check the format, you could emit a terminal character into the data stream at the end of each line (eg, `perl -lane 'print pack("i*", @F)' input` to put a newline after each row) and then fread one row at a time, then do a getchar to make sure there is a `'\n'`, and then at the end do an getchar and ensure that you get EOF...but I really don't think it's worthwhile.

Note that in both of these examples, I've put the size of the matrix as command line arguments.  This seems appropriate, since your code seems intended for interactive use.  If you want to read the parameters from the data stream, that is a fairly trivial change to make.  Just read from the stream instead of parsing the command line.

Comment: Great code, out of curiosity, why do you include libgen.h?

Comment: @KamilCuk for basename

Comment: But note that I've taken out the call to basename.  so that a `const` qualifier can be added.